# Rearrange arrays order by specific level index

Tags: php, arrays

I have been searching this but did not find any solution anywhere. I want to re order my array with a specific index.

Like this:

```
$scoreboard = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'score' => 580,
        'game' => 'google',
    ),
    'bar' => array(
        'score' => 1385,
        'game' => 'facebook',
    ),
    'car' => array(
        'score' => 750,
        'game' => 'tweet',
    ),
);
```

And the output should be like this:

```
$scoreboard = array(
    'bar' => array(
        'score' => 1385,
        'game' => 'facebook',
    ),
    'car' => array(
        'score' => 750,
        'game' => 'tweet',
    ),
    'foo' => array(
        'score' => 580,
        'game' => 'google',
    ),
);
```

See that the array is rearranged with each item's 'score' index. Any help here?

Comment: Does http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php not do what you need?

Comment: You can use http://php.net/uasort and write a custom callback that compares two elements, that are arrays themselves, based on what you find under the "score" key

Comment: What's the point of downvote in this question? I really don't understand this community. -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on on my comment where I suggested to use the [uasort](http://php.net/uasort) function, here is a working sample: http://codepad.org/fBSqHNCC

Comment: Wow that did the job!

Answer (score 1):

Like mishu mentions in the comment, you can use the `uasort`-function

**Example:**

```
$scoreboard = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'score' => 580,
        'game' => 'google',
    ),
    'bar' => array(
        'score' => 1385,
        'game' => 'facebook',
    ),
    'car' => array(
        'score' => 750,
        'game' => 'tweet',
    ),
);

function arrayCompareScore( $a, $b ) {
    if ( $a['score'] == $b['score'] ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ( $a['score'] > $b['score'] ) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort( $scoreboard, 'arrayCompareScore' );
print_r( $scoreboard );
```